# Smooth momentum slowdown in C++/SFML?

Tags: c++, math, vector, sfml

I am making an 'asteroids' game in C++ and SFML, and am wondering about smooth momentum slowdown and speed up. In the original game, when you moved in a direction, you built up 'momentum', which increased whilst the button was held down, and decreased when released. I have started my own version of this. Currently I have a `sf::Vector2f` containing the ship's momentum. It can be negative or positive. The problem is, I can't properly implement slowdown (I've not even attempted speedup yet). I've tried the following;

```
if (plr.momentum.x < 0) {
    plr.momentum.x++;
}
if (plr.momentum.x > 0) {
    plr.momentum.x--;
}
if (plr.momentum.y < 0) {
    plr.momentum.y++;
}
if (plr.momentum.y > 0) {
    plr.momentum.y--;
}
```

With this, after moving, the player is slowly dragged to the top left of the window (coordinates 0,0). I assume this is because a float can be, for example 0.05, meeting the 'more than 0' if statement. From this, it takes one, making it a minus number. The next if statement adds one to it, and this continuously loops. Negative `x` momentum moves you left, and negative `y` momentum moves you up, and visa versa. I would like to know the methodology behind smooth slowdowns and speedups.

Incase you were/are wondering, I use the following code to move the player according to it's momentum;

```
playerSprite.move(plr.momentum);
```

If you are not familiar with SFML, `sf::Vector2f` has a `.x` and `.y`, which are used in `.move` of `sf::Sprite playerSprite`. `.move` moves the player relative to their current position; so if a player is at (5,0), and you do `player.move(sf::Vector2f(-1,0))`, their coordinates would be (4,0).

**EDIT**:
I now have the following code for slowdowns as a suggestion from a friend. The slowdown works perfectly, but after slowing down, it starts moving to the top left again. What is causing this?

```
if (plr.xSlowdown < 0.f) {
    plr.xSlowdown += 0.1f;
}
if (plr.xSlowdown > 0.f) {
    plr.xSlowdown -= 0.1f;
}
if (plr.ySlowdown < 0.f) {
    plr.ySlowdown += 0.1f;
}
if (plr.ySlowdown > 0.f) {
    plr.ySlowdown -= 0.1f;
}

plr.xMomentum = floor(plr.xSlowdown);
plr.yMomentum = floor(plr.ySlowdown);
```

Comment: Re your edit:  I think your current left/topward drift is based on your "floor" operation -- think what happens if `xSlowdown` starts at `+0.05f`, and goes through multiple iterations of your code.  If you want your sprite to come to a dead stop, you should instead add a test inside each `if(){}` statement:  e.g., if the slowdown changes a value from `<0.f` to `>0.f`, it should be set to exactly `0.f` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your spaceship to slow down when the thrusters are off, you should add drag.

Drag applies a force based on the velocity:  the simplest way is to do `F = -K v` for a drag coefficient `K`.  So, if your ship's momentum is stored in `plr.xMomentum` and `plr.yMomentum`, your program would be:

```
// note:  "dt" is your timestep;
//   if you don't have one, just choose some small value for "fraction", like 0.005
float fraction = drag_coefficient_K * dt;
plr.xMomentum -= fraction * plr.xMomentum;
plr.yMomentum -= fraction * plr.yMomentum;
```

Speedup will be based on the orientation of your spaceship:

```
// note: "orientation" is the angle of your spaceship;
//   the units of orientation are determined by "angle_scale",
//   which should be chosen such that "angle_in_radians" is in radians...
float angle_in_radians = angle_scale * orientation;
float thrust_per_timestep = thrust_value * dt;
plr.xMomentum += thrust_per_timestep * cos(angle_in_radians);
plr.yMomentum += thrust_per_timestep * sin(angle_in_radians);
```

The combination of the drag and the thrust effectively puts an upper limit on the speed you can achieve (at least without gravitational assist or something...).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is physics. Very simple physics: F=ma.

You need to have some concept of acceleration, velocity, and position. User input dictates the acceleration. The acceleration changes the velocity, and velocity changes position.

Aside: There is no difference between slowdown and speedup. They're both acceleration.